# Concept is satisfied by a type that would seemingly produce an invalid expression

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

In the following code, the `can_foo` concept tests whether or not a `foo()` member function can be called on an instance of a type. I will use it to test instances of two templates: `base` conditionally enables the `foo` member function, and `derived` overrides `foo` to call into its base's implementation:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept can_foo = requires(T v) {
    v.foo();
};

template <bool enable_foo>
struct base {
    void foo()
        requires enable_foo
    {}
};

template <typename T>
struct derived : T {
    void foo()
    {
        static_cast<T&>(*this).foo();
    }
};
```

If I test whether instances of the `base` template satisfy the concept, it does what I would expect:

```cpp
static_assert(can_foo<base<true>>); //okay
static_assert(not can_foo<base<false>>); //okay
```

When I wrap those types in `derived`, I see:

```cpp
static_assert(can_foo<derived<base<true>>>); //okay
static_assert(not can_foo<derived<base<false>>>); //error: static assertion failed
```

This is surprising! I expected that `derived<base<false>>` would *not* satisfy `can_foo` - its definition of `foo` uses an expression that isn't valid given `T = base<false>`, and using the same expression tested by the concept in an evaluated context results in an error that says as much:

```
int main()
{
    derived<base<false>> v{};
    v.foo(); //error
}
```

The error message isn't at the call site, which is probably relevant; it references the body of `derived<>::foo`. From clang:

```
<source>:18:32: error: invalid reference to function 'foo': constraints not satisfied
        static_cast<T&>(*this).foo();
                               ^
<source>:31:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'derived<base<false>>::foo' requested here
    v.foo(); //"invalid reference to function 'foo'"
      ^
<source>:10:18: note: because 'false' evaluated to false
        requires enable_foo
                 ^
```

clang: https://godbolt.org/z/vh58TTPxo
gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/qMPrzznar

Both compilers produce the same results, so I assume the problem is that there's a subtlety in the standard that I'm missing. Adding a `can_foo<T>` constraint to `derived<T>` or `derived<T>::foo` "fixes" this (that is, `derived<base<false>>` will no longer satisfy `can_foo`), and in a code review I would argue that this constraint should be present - but this is surprising behaviour nonetheless and I'd like to understand what's going on.

So: why does `derived<false>` satisfy `can_foo`?

Comment: Why do you think it is "surprising"? `derived<T>::foo()` has no constraints.

Comment: I think it's surprising because the expression `v.foo()` when `v` is a `derived<base<false>>` produces an error whether or not `derived<T>::foo()` has a constraint. Clearly this doesn't mean that the expression in the concept's requirement is invalid, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *requires-expression* can only detect invalid constructs in the "immediate context" of the expression that is tested. In particular

```
requires(T v) {
    v.foo();
};
```

will not check whether it is actually well-formed to have the call `v.foo()`. If `v.foo()` would be ill-formed due to an ill-formed construct inside the body of the `foo` function, this will not be detected by the *requires-expression* because the body is not in the immediate context.

The question is, what should happen next? Should the *requires-expression* go and instantiate the body of `foo` and give a hard error, or should it return true and give you a hard error later when you attempt to call `v.foo()`? The answer is the second one: instantiation is not performed because it is not required. See [[temp.inst]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#5)

> Unless a function template specialization is a declared specialization, the function template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist or if the existence of the definition affects the semantics of the program. [...]

[temp.inst]/11 additionally implies that the implementation is not permitted to instantiate the definition *unless* it is required.

In an unevaluated context, calling `v.foo()` does not require the definition of `foo` to exist, because [it is not odr-used unless it is potentially evaluated](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#8) and [it is normally the ODR that requires a definition to exist](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#11). (However, there are two situations where referencing a function requires its definition to exist even in an unevaluated context: when the function has a deduced return type or is needed for constant evaluation ([[temp.inst]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#8))). Since the definition is not required to exist, the definition is not instantiated.

You might want to modify `derived::foo` so that it propagates the constraint from `T::foo`, and thus the ill-formedness can be detected by `can_foo<derived<T>>`:

```
void foo() requires can_foo<T> {
    static_cast<T&>(*this).foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`derived` has a `foo` for every template parameter `T`, it just cannot always be instantiated. When trying to instantiate `derived<base<false>>::foo` where you try to to call it in `main`, you get the error message that the instantiation is not valid since foo cannot be called for the type `base<false>`.

Rules regarding when instantiation is optional and/or required in the standard would be [[temp.inst]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst).
I'm however not able to point to a conclusive passage that says that
checking whether `derived<base<false>>::foo` exists in the context of the `static_assert` does not require instantiation. Is it the same as overload resolution checking? ["If the function selected by overload resolution can be determined without instantiating a class template definition, it is unspecified whether that instantiation actually takes place."](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#9)

If you want `derived::foo` to only be available if it can be instantiated, you could require `can_foo` on its T.

```
template <typename T>
struct derived : T {
  void foo() requires can_foo<T>
  {
      static_cast<T&>(*this).foo();
  }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EqrMq4Moq